# Web-element is visible and enabled but .click() fails in python selenium with phantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I want to click on the `Next`-button at `https://free-proxy-list.net/`. The XPATH selector is `//*[@id="proxylisttable_next"]/a`

I do this with the following piece of code:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2, poll_frequency = 0.1).until
(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="proxylisttable_next"]/a')))
    if (element.is_enabled() == True) and (element.is_displayed() == True):
        element.click()
        print "next button located and clicked" # printed in case of success
```

Subsequently, I get all the IPs from the table like this:

```
IPs = WebDriverWait(driver, 2, poll_frequency = 0.1).until
(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ':nth-child(n) > td:nth-child(1)')))
```

Although the CSS_selector is the same for all tabs, and although I get a `next button located and clicked`, the IPs output is the same for both tabs (i.e. it seems like the `Next`-button never was clicked). **Additionally, there is no Exception thrown.**

**Therefore, there must be something fundamentally wrong with my approach.**

**How to click on visible & enabled buttons correctly in phantomJS using python/selenium?**

For your understanding, here is the html of the page section I am referring to:

[image: Target HTML]

Comment: post if you are getting any error

Comment: just updated - there is no Exception of any kind thrown

Comment: then the element is not clickable. Wait for some time if there is any kind of hidden lay-over. or use `driver.execute_script` Js will do it for you.

Comment: @PrakashPalnati if the element is not clickable, why does the above code return "next button located and clicked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see there could be two possible causes:

1. The click was not registered, though this is highly unlikely. You can look at other ways to click like JavascriptExecutor's click.
2. (Most likely) The find elements are queried right after the click is performed and before the Page 2 results are loaded. Since elements is visible from page 1, it exits immediately with the list of elements from page 1. An ideal way of doing this would be (using psuedocode as I am not familiar with python)

   a. Get the current page number

   b. Get all the IPs from the current page

   c. Click Next

   d. Check if (Current page + 1 ) page has become active (class 'active' is added to the Number 2)

   e. Get all the elements from the current page

Comment: Following your suggestions, i tested if the element is enabled, which returned a StaleElementReferenceException - I will move to the driver.execute_script-part suggested by Prakash Palnati

Answer (score 0):

I am the OP and for anyone coming across a similar problem - The `Next` element was no longer attached to the DOM following its selection, which caused `StaleElementReferenceException` when printing `element.is_enabled()` or when clicking it - a detailed solution can be found [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/20520)